# How to load a database to a user app in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jsx

I am building an app that shows quotes and small texts to an user daily and I am already using async storage to store user preferences. Though I need a way to store these hundreds of quotes too. As well as recall one every day for the notification and everytime the user asks for a new one. I could just write it all on an object in the code in a file for it and import everywhere I need it but that doesn't sound like a good option or load it all in async to be recovered when needed like my user preferences. But I can't tell yet which since I am new to RN.

Comment: You need the new data should remain even after the app is closed?

Comment: No if the app is not using it I don't need the data

Comment: I think, the best way is to use Context API in this case. I can provide you with an example code if you are interested.